# How to drop primary index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I used SQL Server 2017. The executed query is as follows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE T11 (
    COL VARCHAR NOT NULL,  
    COL2 VARCHAR, 
    COL3 VARCHAR 
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX PK_T11 ON T11 (
    COL ASC
)
GO


CREATE TABLE T12 (
    COL VARCHAR NOT NULL 
)
GO


CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX PK_T12 ON T12 (
    COL ASC
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FK_T11_TO_T12 ON T12 (
    COL ASC
)
GO

ALTER TABLE T12
    ADD
        CONSTRAINT FK_T11_TO_T12
        FOREIGN KEY (
            COL
        )
        REFERENCES T11 (
            COL
        )
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO
```

I ran the following query to remove it.

```sql
DROP INDEX T11.PK_T11
GO

DROP INDEX T12.PK_T12
GO

DROP TABLE T11
GO


DROP TABLE T12
GO
```

When I do the syntax to remove the index, I get the following error:

> An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed on index 'T11.PK_T11'. It is being used for FOREIGN KEY constraint enforcement.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why are you dropping the indexes and then the tables? Just drop the tables and the indexes will go with them.  `DROP TABLE T11, T12`

Comment: Well, you have to drop them the other way around first - `DROP TABLE dbo.T12, dbo.T11;` But like Martin I'm confused why you're bothering with the indexes separately, but more importantly, why you're trying to delete the parent table before you delete the child table that references it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand If the index is specified incorrectly, I thought that it would be better to just delete the index than to delete the table itself.

However, the actual query didn't work the way I thought it would.

Is there a way to delete only the index without deleting the table?

Comment: Yes but you have to drop the foreign key constraint first (as suggested by the error message).

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a Foreign Key constraint is that you have a column (or set of columns) in a table (like T12) that references a column (or set of columns) in another table (like T11), such that that column in T12 can only contain values that exist in the corresponding column in T11.

But to do this, there must be a unique index or primary key on the column(s) in T11.

So if you're trying to remove that index on T11 (or drop the whole table T11), it will be prevented by the Foreign Key constraint on T12. Unless you first remove the constraint on T12 or drop the whole table T12. Then you can remove the index on T11 (or drop that table).

Make sense? It's like removing the product list while you've still got orders that refer to those products. It's not just the product values that need to be in the products table, but the list (index) of products needs to be there too.